# Should I create instance of module or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a module that looks something like this:

```
module.exports = {
    property1: {}, 
    property2: {},
    fucnct1: function(one, two){
        this.property1 = one;
        this.property2 = two;
    }
}
```

I then do the following

```
var myModule = require("./myModule.js");

var api = {
    handleRequest: function(req, res){
        // someValue1 and someValue2 are different for each request
        myModule.funct1(someValue1, someValue2)
    }
};

// Handle the http request.
handleRequest = function(req, res){
    var apiInst = Object.create(api);
    apiInst.handleRequest(req, res);
};

// Start the server
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
server.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Listening on port " + port || "Could not start server");
});
```

When 2 or more people hit the the server at the same time, do they share those properties (`myModule.property1` and `myModule.property2`) within the module, or are they unique for each user?

Should I be creating an instance of this module for each user, or not?

Comment: From my understanding of `require(module_name)`, the module only executes the very first time you call require. This makes `require` almost act like a global variable that you can import. For example, if you set `property1` to `Math.random()`, then every time you call `require` and access `property1`, it will be the same during that running of the program. There is a method you can use to "delete" cached modules but I'd have to look it up.

Comment: Re-reading your question, I guess that's not really addressing your question since you're not calling `require` multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the two properties are shared.  You can't really create instances of the module, but instead you can export an object and create an instance of that.